# Could you please expand a little bit and explain in more detail what this quote by Hamlet means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "And blessed are those
>
> Whose blood and judgment are so well commingled,
>
> That they are not a pipe for Fortune’s finger
>
> To sound what stop she please"

Something else I'd like to know is about the grammatical  structure of *"To sound what stop she please"*. Seems strange to me! Could you be more specific about that?

Comment: Pipe = flute-like instrument.  Stop. Compare the "stops" on a pipe organ. These blessed people have such an even temperament that they are not merely an instrument for (Dame) Fortune to play on, sounding whatever note *might please* her.

Comment: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0080%3Asection%3D4%3Asubsection%3D12%3Aparagraph%3D361

Comment: or "whatever note she *may find* pleasing to her".

Comment: @TRomano:I'm sorry,but I still didn't catch what you said about it..:(

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: sound (v): emit or cause to emit sound. Stop(n): a set of organ pipes of a particular tone and range of pitch.

Comment: A side point: we would now say "to sound what stop she pleases."  This is an example of the subjunctive mood disappearing from modern usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shakespeare's works are full of language like this. In less flowery language, the Bard is saying that these people take their fates into their own hands and are NOT at the mercy of whatever fortune, good or ill, the world may bring them. The people he describes are those with both good judgment and the courage to act. That's what he means by "blood and judgment so well commingled".

You would not hear language like this in modern discourse, though you might read it in poetry occasionally. Structurally:

```
... a pipe for Fortune's finger
to sound what stop she please
```

This phrase describes Fortune's finger playing the stops (holes) on the pipe according to her own desires.

Comment: @RobertMunn.Thank you.I just wanted to say how much I appreciate the work you are doing here.Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth noting that the contrast being expressed is between Hamlet and his rock-steady friend Horatio. Hamlet is enlisting Horatio's aid in discovering whether King Claudius will react in a self-incriminating way to the play (play-within-the-play) that is about to be performed for the court. Hamlet at this point is plagued equally by suspicion and doubt, and is telling his friend that he needs to rely on a steadier judgment than his own. When he says

> And blessed are those
>   Whose blood and judgment are so well commingled,
>   That they are not a pipe for Fortune’s finger

he means someone not as passionate and over-wrought as he is. To put it in plainer English:

> Look, Horatio, I'm quite knocked about by my passions so that I can't rely on my own judgment. Do me a favor and let me rely on your good sense and judgment, for though I am flitting about in fits of passion, which may make me deceive myself, you are a rock on whose judgment I can depend.

Sounds better the way Shakespeare says it, of course, but that's what he means.

Comment: @Robusto.I really appreciate your help.Thank you. I would really like to choose both answers.Both are right.They complement each other. But It seems we are only allowed to choose one answer:(

Answer (score 0):

he is saying that when the mind meets the body instead of the body ruling the mind or the mind ruling the body, you reach a particular balance that allows you to be a free owner of your will, you wont need fortune because thats a fortune by itself and there is no room for ramdom "luck"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).